# exporting data from a database to another _mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'x' at row 1

Tags: mysql, django

Hi I have  a project in PHP and I want develop the same with Django, for many reasons I decided to create a new database, so now I have to export all the data from the old one to the new one,for  doing that I use the models I developed for Django, it worked  until I stuck with this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'bloomberg' at row 1
```

this  is the model of the table  where I am experimenting  this issue:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company)
address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
first_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
role = models.CharField(max_length=20)
sector = models.CharField(max_length=45)
work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
contact_source = models.CharField(max_length=30)
alt_work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
work_fax = models.CharField(max_length=30)
bloomberg = models.CharField(max_length=60)
work_email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
research_email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
product_focus = models.CharField(max_length=2)
preferred_email = models.CharField(max_length=60)
job_title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
created_by = models.CharField(max_length=25)
legal_entity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
status= models.ForeignKey(Status)
title = models.CharField(max_length=5)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
country = models.CharField(max_length=15)
city= models.CharField(max_length=20)
created_date=models.DateTimeField('creation date ')
updated_date=models.DateTimeField('update date ')
updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)
parent = models.CharField(max_length=45)
address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
new = models.BooleanField()
hided = models.BooleanField()
employee = models.BooleanField()

def __unicode__(self):
    s = u" Contact "
    return s + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

the fields in both databases have the same length,so I do not understand the error, after googling I noticed that usually  this problem is solved fixing the dimensions of the column, but this is not my case. can somebody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like 60 Chars are not enough for your "bloombergs". Try to set this higher like:

```
bloomberg = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Notice, that you will also have to do this on database level if you already synced your models. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response; of course I can change the dimension of the field, but it is anyway quite strange, because on the master database this field is 60 chars and I got the error for a record that has a bloomberg field of 26 chars, I will try your suggestion but the problem will be still there.